# Removing all special characters except "some" apostrophes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a function that removes all special characters (including periods) except apostrophes when they are naturally part of a word. The regex pattern I've made is supposed to remove anything that doesn't fit the schema of `word` either followed by an apostrophe `'` and/or another `word`:

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z?'?a-z ]/g, ``)
}

console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string.`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string with random stuff.*/_- '`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`'''`))
```

As you can see from the snippet it works well *except* for removing the rogue apostrophes.

And if I add something like `[\s'\s]` or `[']` to the pattern it breaks it completely. Why is it doing this and what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate the pattern with `'\B`, which will match and remove apostrophes which are *not* followed by a word character, eg `ab'` or `ab'@`, while preserving strings like `ab'c`:

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/'\B|[^a-z'? ]/g, ``)
}

console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string.`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string with random stuff.*/_- '`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`'''`))
```

(you can also remove the duplicated characters from the character set)

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I want it to :)

Comment: Do you really want to lowercase everything? (If not, you may use the case-insensitive flag)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one very easy solution. To remove certain characteristics from a string, you can run a bunch of if-statements through a while loop. This allows you to chose exactly which symbols to remove.

```
while (increment < string.length)
{
    if (string[increment] == "!")
    }
        delete "!";
    }

    increment += 1;
}
```

That's a simple rundown of what'll look like (not actual code) to give you a sense of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what went wrong with yours as I can't see what you attempted. However, I got this to work.

```js
function removeSpecialCharacters(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  // reduce duplicate apostrophes to single
  str = str.replace(/'+/g,`'`);
  // get rid of wacky chars
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z'\s]/g,'');
  // replace dangling apostrophes
  str =  str.replace(/(^|\s)'(\s|$)/g, ``);

  return str;
}

console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string.`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`I'm a string with random stuff.*/_- '`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`'''`))
console.log(removeSpecialCharacters(`regex 'til i die`))
```